# VB.net 2010 RDLC REPORTS NOT WORKING

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

am new to visual studio 2010 though i have worked with Visual studio 2005 to develop applications before
Apparently am developing a Child Welfare Society ERP that has different modules
bu am currently working on the reports and i have chosen to work with Rdlc reports which i have used before in Visual studio 2005 but i have hit a snag in the visual studio 2010 am using the following code to populate the records on a listview control

```
Private Sub btnReport_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnReport.Click
        Dim Ds As New ClientDataSet
        Dim drow As DataRow
        Dim i As Integer
        For i = 0 To lstveClient.Items.Count - 1
            drow = Ds.Tables("ClientDataTable").NewRow()
            drow("ClientIdNo") = lstveClient.Items(i).Text
            drow("ClientName") = lstveClient.Items(i).SubItems(1).Text
            drow("PhoneNo") = lstveClient.Items(i).SubItems(2).Text
            drow("PAddress") = lstveClient.Items(i).SubItems(3).Text
            drow("Quantity") = lstveClient.Items(i).SubItems(4).Text


            Ds.Tables("ClientDataTable").Rows.Add(drow)
        Next i
        Dim freport As New eReports
        eReports.ReportViewer1.Reset()
        eReports.ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ProcessingMode.Local
        eReports.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = System.Environment.CurrentDirectory & "\rptClient.rdlc"
        eReports.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear()
        eReports.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(New     Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource("ClientDataset_ClientDataTable", Ds.Tables(0)))
        eReports.ReportViewer1.DocumentMapCollapsed = True
        eReports.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
        eReports.ShowDialog()

    End Sub
```

as is the norm in vb 2005 i have created a different form(eReports) on which i have docked the report viewer
on clicking on the report button am getting this message @ a data source instance has not been supplied for the data source "ClientDataset" what could be wrong???
where could be i be going wrong please assist

Answer (score 0):

Well if read the error, the error is expecting a datasource named **ClientDataset**.

```
a data source instance has not been supplied for the data source ClientDataset
```

yet you provide a dataset named **"ClientDataset_ClientDataTable"**

```
eReports.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(New     Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource("ClientDataset_ClientDataTable", Ds.Tables(0)))
```

I think the adjusting the line to the following line may fix your problem

```
eReports.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(New     Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource("ClientDataset", Ds.Tables(0)))
```

But i might be wrong...